# Form field will not populate data

Tags: php, sql

I have the following form field that will not populate data on reloading the information.  It saves the information fine to the sql database.

Form Code :

```
        <select value="<?php echo isset($results['status']) ? $results['status']: ''; ?>" class="form-control" name="data[status]" placeholder="Status">
    <option value="Apples" <?= ($results['status']) == 'Apples' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Apples</option>
<option value="Oranges" <?= ($results['status']) == 'Oranges' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Oranges</option>
```

Sql Code :

```
if( !empty( $data ) ){ //$this->pre($data);
            // escape variables for security
            if( isset( $data['data']['table'] ) && !empty( $data['data']['table'] )){
$status = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, trim( $data['data']['status'] ) );
if(empty($id)){
    $uuid = uniqid();
    $query = "INSERT INTO table(`id`, `status`, `uuid`) 
        VALUES (NULL, '$status', '$uuid')";
```

I know this is probably something stupid that I am missing, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit :

Form field saves to database, but form field will not retain saved data on sql query

Comment: I didn't get your question, what is missing? What should've been happening that it isn't?

Comment: Where is $results['status'] defined? What is it's value if you echo it?

Comment: could it be that in your form it should be `$data['status' ], and not `$results['status']` ? If not, pleas try `var_dump($results);`

Answer (score 0):

This one is helpfull for you:

```
<select name="data[]">
    <option value="<?php echo $results['status']; ?>" <?php if($results['status']=="active") { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>  >Active</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $results['status']; ?>" <?php if($results['status']=="active") { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>  >underscreen</option>
</select>
```

Comment: while i guess this answer is correct, elaborating a bit could help, i think (that is: point to the `selected="selected"` part

Comment: @Burki I added my option values for clarity of what is not populating.  Tried the above code to no avail...

Comment: @Steven did you check the source code of the generated html? Does it show `selected` (or better still: `selected="selected"` ) for the correct option?

Comment: @Burki sadly it does not show anything selected, nor can I get data back when I insert "<? php echo $results[status] ?> , HOWEVER anything I save in the form DOES write to the database